# Website loading with missing letters for a split second on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Experiencing an odd issue when my website loads on mobile. Simply put, random letters in displayed words are missing during the initial load period; it often lasts for a single second before fully correcting itself (displaying all letters).

Have not been able to locate similar issues in other questions. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Missing Letters]

Comment: Make sure you are using TrueType font(s).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm using Gotham font from Typography.com. I've never had this problem in the past (going back a year), but I also have no idea when it started. Is there a problem with this font?

Comment: I have no reason to think there's any particular issue with Gotham. It's just an idea. Try playing around with different fonts and see if the problem persists/disappears.